# Rails checkbox_tag with ajax

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, checkbox

I'm trying to figure out how to pass data with ajax using a checkbox in Rails 3.2.11.  I have the following line in my view

```
<%= check_box_tag(
        "institution_ids_#{inst.name.gsub(" ", "")}",
          inst.id,
          false,
        data: {
          remote: true,
          institution_id: inst.id}) %>
```

When I change the status of the checkbox, I can see that the controller is correctly getting called (specifically the index method of the controller, which is what I want as that is the view I'm in), however, I cannot seem to access the institution_id variable from the params hash on the controller.  Can someone please explain how I use ajax to pass data from the view to the controller within a checkbox.  I thought the remote: true function would correctly call the controller (which is does) with the additional parameters that I set (which it doesn't).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Why don't you use jquery to make `Ajax` call.

```
<%= check_box_tag( "institution_ids_#{inst.name.gsub(" ", "")}", inst.id, false %>

<script>
     $('#checkbox_id').change(function(){
        $.get('controller/action?inst_id='+$(this).val(), function(data,status){
            if(status == 'success'){
              alert(data)
             }
        })
     })
   </script>
```

In controller:

```
def action
   inst_id = params[:inst_id]
   #do something
   render :text => "success" 
end
```

Comment: I figured I could do something like this.  I have a lot of checkboxes, and I figured this would be more readable if I can do everything inline.  Is that just not possible?

Comment: try using like this: `:data =>  { :remote => true, :url => { :action =>  action_name, :institution_id =>  inst.id} }`

Comment: So the above didn't work, but this did data: {remote: true, url: url_for(action: :index, institution_id: inst.id), institution_id: inst.id}