# How to create an object when a check_box is checked?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

Is there any way to get a check_box to function in the same way as button_to, for example, so that when the box is checked an object is created?

The code for my button_to is as follows:

```
<%= button_to("Yes", :action => "create", :controller => "objects", :object => {:boolean => 'true', :object_1.id => current.id}) %>
```

I want this same event to occur, but when a check_box is checked rather than when a button is clicked. It would be cool if the object could be destroyed when the box is unchecked as well. Is this possible?

Comment: Not really possible, a checkbox is a form input so it doesn't submit anything.   You could mimic a checkbox with a button and some fancy js/css though.

Comment: OK, so best to just stick with the button then. Thanks for the input!

Comment: you want create what kind of object? (a javacript object, a database object, a rails object )

Comment: Hey @ruby_noobie, try something like this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14780929/rails-checkbox-tag-with-ajax

Also if you want to check/uncheck and then press a button to submit the checkboxes (both checked and "unchecked") you can use some rails magic, give a look to: http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper/check_box_tag and http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper/check_box

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In short, no unless you expand your interest into Javascript and AJAX. The long answer is that a checkbox returns no value at all if it is not checked, not a nil value, nothing. The returned parameter looks like this `{}` ie empty. Whereas you are much safer reacting to a value like `{destroy: "yes"}` which you can implement with a button.

If you are dead set on a check-box, maybe look at ways of using two checkbox images as your button (one for set, one for not set). Javascript is your friend here, but it is more work and I wouldn't personally do it.

Comment: Thank you for the tip. I will stick with the button and save my check box dreams for another day.

Comment: It seems a rather absolute negative when an AJAX call could make the checkbox behave in the desired way, with or without submitting the form... and there's also the option of creating a hidden form input using javascript, so that the object is created only once the form is submitted. Why so negative?

Comment: Taking into account the relative inexperience of the original poster, I don't believe pointing down that path would be productive. There is a steep learning curve between how check-boxes work in Rails and how Javascript and AJAX work. However I take your point and will adjust my answer to be not so absolute.